# Missing unity-panel-service Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity

I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04, now the menu bars (top and bottom) are missing. I tried reinstalling ubuntu and ubuntu-desktop but the bars are still missing. After trying to reset unity, I found that I'm missing the unity-panel-service, so I was wondering how I should download the unity-panel-service.